# Shopify price conditions not being honoured

Tags: if-statement, shopify, price

I have no idea why these conditions are not working on my collection-item.liquid template.

```
{% if product.price >= 5000 && product.price <= 50000 %}
    <img src="https:{{ '01.png' | asset_url }}" />

{% elsif product.price > 50000 && product.price <= 100000 %}
    <img src="https:{{ '02.png' | asset_url }}" />

{% elsif product.price > 100000 %}
    <img src="https:{{ '03.png' | asset_url }}" />

{% endif %}
```

Instead of the expected result, all the products are showing 01.png

If I do this...

```
{{ product.price }}
```

...I can see the product prices are showing correctly (meaning that a $50 product returns 5000 for example).

I've also tried the values as strings instead of integers, but that did not fix the problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

My bad - Shopify does not support `&&` as an operator. It has to be `and` instead.